# Adding Item to a List

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to take a string that is entered by the user and transfer it to a list. When I click the add button The list clears out. Here is the code. Thank you fo your help

```
Const ModelPrompt As String = "Input Car Model"
Const ModelTitle As String = "Car Model"

Const PricePrompt As String = "Input Car MSRP"
Const PriceTitle As String = "Car MSRP"


carModel = InputBox(ModelPrompt, ModelTitle)
carPrice = InputBox(PricePrompt, PriceTitle)

Do While carModel <> String.Empty _
AndAlso carPrice <> String.Empty

    carListBox.Items.Add(carModel)
    msrpListBox.Items.Add(carPrice)

Loop
```

Comment: I think you need to post up your whole code. Where's the List initialised?

Comment: I just need to take the input from the user and add it to the list. That is all the code for button.

Comment: I feel it is a simple mistake, but I do not know what I am doing wrong thank you.

Comment: the carListBox variable is the name of the list

Comment: I don't think the list is clearing out, looks like you're just hung up in your loop. I don't see the need for the `Do While` loop...if carModel and carPrice have data, that loop will never end.

Comment: that looks more like it is working with a ListBOX not a List.  Please read [Ask] AndAlso take the [Tour].

Comment: @Plutonix good eye eagle eye ;) I noticed that as well.

Comment: @Codexer  List<T>, ListBox, ListView, SortedList ...its all the same in Visual Basics

Comment: Why do you have a loop there?  Is the idea to let the user keep adding multiple items?  If so then you would need to call `InputBox` again inside the loop.  As it is you're only prompting the user for data once and then adding that one set of data to the `ListBox` over and over forever.  If you only want one set of data then get rid of the loop and use an `If` statement.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code my friend

```
    Const ModelPrompt As String = "Input Car Model"
    Const ModelTitle As String = "Car Model"

    Const PricePrompt As String = "Input Car MSRP"
    Const PriceTitle As String = "Car MSRP"

    Dim carModel As Object = InputBox(ModelPrompt, ModelTitle)
    Dim carPrice As Object = InputBox(PricePrompt, PriceTitle)

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(carModel) = False And String.IsNullOrEmpty(carPrice) = False Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(carModel)
        ListBox2.Items.Add(carPrice)
    End If
```